# Add tag to a python file in Windows 10

Tags: python, windows-10, tags

I am trying to tag my python files in Windows 10. However, it seems not to working. I right click on the file, see the details, go to details tab and then... nothing?
I see some file properties, but I can't change them. The only thing I am able to do is "remove properties and personal information". What do you suggest?

Example:
I have a file which gets numbers as an input from the user and sorts the numbers.
My tags would be "sorting" and "input"

Comment: Can you please explain why you need tags? I'm pretty sure there is a better solution. If it's for windows search, then the question is why do you need the search at all (and again, why do you need tags to search).

Comment: Hi @Dmitry. I want to sort my python files using tags. For example, if I click on "sorting" I want to see all the files I wrote for sorting

Comment: Why not just organize the files? I.e. all these files should belong to a directory "sorting". I'm asking because your question is about a feature that I never heard to be needed, so it seems like you have an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) and are trying to solve some standard problem in a weird way.

Comment: A file could have more tags, like "sorting", "userInput" and others, so I figured out this could be the best approach to solve the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is my understanding that, out of the box, Windows 10 supports a limited number of file types for tagging. Python files are not among those supported types. Therefore, some additional steps need to be taken.

This [article](https://www.techsupportalert.com/content/use-free-utility-help-make-your-windows-files-easier-organize-and-find.htm) details how to use the free [File Meta Association Manager](https://github.com/Dijji/FileMeta/wiki/Using-the-File-Meta-Association-Manager) available from GitHub to enable tags for file types that aren't supported out of the box.

1. Once File Meta Association Manager [installer file](https://github.com/Dijji/FileMeta/releases) is downloaded from the repository release page install it.
2. Under the File Extensions list, scroll down and find .py. Then on the left side, select the "Simple" profile.
3. Once the simple profile is selected, then click "Add File Meta Handler".
4. Click the button to Restart Explorer.
5. Open Explorer and right click on a py file and add tags. Note, I did not need to update the registry for this to work.

[image: Main window for making changes]

[image: Select Simple]

[image: Happy tagging...]

**What if py isn't in the list?**
From [this article](https://karl-voit.at/2019/11/26/Tagging-Files-With-Windows-10/):

> If you can not find a specific file extension in the File Meta Association Manager, no application has registered the file extension so far. If you do associate a file extension with an application ("Always open with ..."), this does not create a registry entry. Therefore, associating an extension with an application is not sufficient that this extension gets listed in the File Meta Association Manager.

> To add an extension not listed yet, you have to start the registry editor with administrator privileges, go to "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE" → "SOFTWARE" → "Classes" and choose "New → Key" from the context menu.

Comment: Thank you very much for your kind and clear answer!!!